How do I monitor Apple Wireless Direct Link traffic to and from my macOS (15.1.1) computer?
Apparently, Apple Wireless Direct Link is a Wi-Fi-like, unencrypted proprietary Apple protocol used by AirDrop, AirPlay, Apple Watch, Game Center, and Sidecar. I’d like to see what data it’s transmitting.
So, how do I monitor AWDL packets to and from my macOS computer (macOS Sequoia 15.1.1 on an iMac 24”)? There’s an entry for the awdl0 interface in Wireshark 4.4.2 for macOS, but it doesn’t seem to capture anything.

Since 3.0 Wireshark has embedded AWDL data types. Are you doing things that would cause macOS to be active on that interface? https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/a/awdl.html also, of no one answers, editing this to show how you installed wireshark (which guide) and precisely how you set up the app might help someone help you.
